# How to add/enabled ticker sound in CupertinoPicker/CupertinoDatePicker for iOS in flutter?

Tags: iphone, flutter, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

I am bit new for flutter. I used `CupertinoDatePicker` but ticker sound missing from it for iOS. so is there any way to enabled it or add it manually when the date-picker is scrolling?
I checked for native iOS date-picker it's working fine only for flutter it's not working.
Here is my implementation for date picker,

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
                    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                    initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                    onDateTimeChanged: (_) {},
                    maximumYear: DateTime.now().year,
                   )
```

and I imported `import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';` for cupertino component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a [long time opened issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37329) regarding this. You can track if from there.

Answer (score 0):

Note : It's working only in IOS

You can use this on `onDateTimeChanged`

```
SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);
```

Full code is

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
  initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
  onDateTimeChanged: (value) {
    SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);
  },
),
```